# cUrl getting contents of url containing "ü" U+00FC %c3%bc

Tags: php, curl, encoding

I am trying to get information about groceries, title, image, price etc.

All other URLs work fine and the cUrl response is exactly as expected.

The problem I am having is when URLs contain accented latin/non-standard url/non-english characters like ü or è.

I've tried everything I can think of, but there is probably a simply solution I am missing:

```
stringtest.php?url=http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/desserts/g%C3%BC-lemon-pots-3x45g
stringtest.php?url=http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/desserts/gü-lemon-pots-3x45g
stringtest.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sainsburys.co.uk%2Fshop%2Fgb%2Fgroceries%2Fdesserts%2Fg%C3%BC-lemon-pots-3x45g
```

This my code for testing cUrl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
  $url = $_GET['url'];

  echo curlUrl($url);

  function curlUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    $cookie_file = "/tmp/cookie/cookie1.txt";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $html;
  }

?>
  <form action="stringtest.php" method="get" id="process">
    <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Url" autofocus>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result I get from cUrl is Sainsburys' 404 page claiming the page isn't found. 
Copying http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/desserts/gü-lemon-pots-3x45g from the url bar results in the URL encoded version of ü (%C3%BC) being copied, as expected. When entering the URL in the browser, ü and %C3%BC can both be used to reach the actual product page so why does Sainsburys return a 404 when cUrl'd?

I've tried various things such as `urldecode()`, using the exact headers the browser uses, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the Sainsbury website itself.

The server returns a 404 when you don't send a valid cookie.

Did you try reloading?

I tried

```
stringtest.php?url=http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/desserts/gü-chocolate-ganache-pots-3x45g
```

and it worked with a valid cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it responded as expected when I included the cookie information from a browser request. It seems odd that [link](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/lamb/sainsburys-lamb-half-leg-%28approx-1kg%29) doesn't require a cookie but URLs like the one in question does!

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
wget http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/desserts/g%C3%BC-lemon-pots-3x45g
```

The response is:

```
http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/bakery
Resolving www.sainsburys.co.uk (www.sainsburys.co.uk)... 109.94.142.1
Connecting to www.sainsburys.co.uk (www.sainsburys.co.uk)|109.94.142.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/gb/groceries/bakery?langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=xbYM3SJja%2F1mDOxJIVlKl9vZN6zjdlTL4MSiHOKiUMQoum9OkLwoTv6wj27CjUXwqM4%2BsteXag0O%0AQOWiHuS8onFdmoVLWlJyZ7hXaMhcMW9MIMMAsnPdWTPEzSEnOP5a&ddkey=http:AjaxAutoCompleteDisplayView [following]
--2014-10-07 11:56:11-- http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/gb/groceries/bakery?langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=xbYM3SJja%2F1mDOxJIVlKl9vZN6zjdlTL4MSiHOKiUMQoum9OkLwoTv6wj27CjUXwqM4%2BsteXag0O%0AQOWiHuS8onFdmoVLWlJyZ7hXaMhcMW9MIMMAsnPdWTPEzSEnOP5a&ddkey=http:AjaxAutoCompleteDisplayView
Reusing existing connection to www.sainsburys.co.uk:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

To follow the redirect in curl, use the -L flag:

```
curl -L http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/desserts/g%C3%BC-lemon-pots-3x45g
```